# C# repository pattern SQL query with Entity Framework 6 exception data reader is incompatible with specified entity

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-6, repository-pattern

I tried to execute a custom SQL query. However I get the following error when I execute my method.

> Source: Entity Framework
>
> Message: The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'SomeProject.Data.Entities.Config'. A member of the type, 'Id', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

This is my method:

```
private readonly IRepositoryAsync<Config> _configRepository;

private IEnumerable<Config> getConfig()
{
    var sqlCommand = "select * from tbl_Config";

    return this._configRepository.SelectQuery(sqlCommand);
}
```

This is my entity class:

```
public class Config : Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string ValueType { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

This is my `IRepositoryAsync`:

```
public interface IRepositoryAsync<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, ITrackable
{
    Task<TEntity> FindAsync(params object[] keyValues);
    Task<TEntity> FindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, params object[] keyValues);
    Task<bool> DeleteAsync(params object[] keyValues);
    Task<bool> DeleteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, params object[] keyValues);
    Task<int> ExecuteCustomSQL(string sqlCommand, params object[] parameters);
}
```

This is my .SqlQuery method within the repository:

```
public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> SelectQuery(string query, params object[] parameters)
{
    return this.Set.SqlQuery(query, parameters).AsQueryable();
}
```

Here is the mapping:

```
// Table & Column Mappings
this.ToTable("db.TBL_CONFIG");
this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("PK_CONF");
this.Property(t => t.Key).HasColumnName("KEY");
this.Property(t => t.Value).HasColumnName("VALUE");
this.Property(t => t.ValueType).HasColumnName("VALUETYPE");
this.Property(t => t.Description).HasColumnName("DESCRIPTION");
```

The SQL command I have chosen is a simple one since I wanted to test the `.SqlQuery` method first. It says that it can't find the the column name for "Id" although I checked the mapping and it is definitely there.

Did I miss something else?

Comment: If you put a brakpoint at `return this.Set.SqlQuery(query, parameters).AsQueryable();`, can you verify if the query is correct and you are targetting the correct database?

Comment: Can you include your database schema?

Comment: @Stefan I'll do that. Give me a second

Comment: @ColinM I can give you the mapping to the database columns if that helps you?

Comment: `SqlQuery` method does not take mappings into account. It expects the sql to contain all entity property names (not column names), so if you have differences, you have to use select with column aliases instead of *.

Comment: @Stefan yeah it targets the right database. If I use other methods within my repository such as 'await this._configRepository.Query().SelectAsync();' it will return the result just fine. It is only the SqlQuery that won't work which I do not understand.

Comment: @IvanStoev can you elaborate this? So I understand that my sqlcommand should look like this: "select TBL_CONFIG.PK_CONF, TBL_CONFIG.KEY, ...   from TBL_CONFIG" ?

Comment: No, it should be something like this "select PK_CONF Id, Key, Value, ValueType, Description from tbl_Config". Note the "Id" alias.

Comment: @IvanStoev I tried it this morning and you were right it works now! "select PK_CONF as Id, ..." returned the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @IvanStoev I have solved it now. Indeed the method does not take mappings into account. Therefore it expects sql to contain all entity property names (not column names).

**The mapping:**

```
// Table & Column Mappings
this.ToTable("db.TBL_CONFIG");
this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("PK_CONF");
this.Property(t => t.Key).HasColumnName("KEY");
this.Property(t => t.Value).HasColumnName("VALUE");
this.Property(t => t.ValueType).HasColumnName("VALUETYPE");
this.Property(t => t.Description).HasColumnName("DESCRIPTION");
```

As you see in the line `this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("PK_CONF");` there is a difference between the entity property name and the column name.

**The solution sql command:**

```
private readonly IRepositoryAsync<Config> _configRepository;

private IEnumerable<Config> getConfig()
{
    var sqlCommand = "select PK_CONF AS Id, Key, Value, ValueType, Description from TBL_CONFIG";

    return this._configRepository.SelectQuery(sqlCommand);
}
```